# c# String Concat from list

Tags: c#

```
List<String> A = new List<string>();
A.Add("1");
A.Add("2");
A.Add("3");

string joined = String.Join("\",\"", A);
```

So geting output string like 1","2","3

But we requred joined=  "1","2","3"

How can this possible

thanks

Comment: You simply joined items of list A using a separator which in your case is `","`, the output would be like this: item1<separator>item2<separator>item3 (in your case separator is `","`). if you want heading and trailing double quote, you should add it manually.

Answer (score 2):

```
string joined = "\"" + String.Join("\",\"", A) + "\"";
```

or maybe

```
string joined = String.Join(",", A.Select(s => "\"" + s + "\""));
```

Comment: The first of these looks cleaner to me, in that it will produce far fewer temporary strings.

Comment: @JonSkeet for perfomance / computer - yes, for human - second variant should be better because you read code as logic without guessing the trick... regualr deal.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Maybe this calls for a custom JoinSurrounded method :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I bet you can write such method with plain `IL` :D

Answer (score 0):

The [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method joins multiple items in a collection using the delimiter you specify.

So when you run this line of code:

```
string joined = String.Join("\",\"", A);
```

You've specified that the delimiter that separates your items is a comma in quotes:

```
","
```

That string only appears *between* items, not before the first one or after the last one.

You'll have to add a quote before the first and after the last manually.